# Parse RSS feed using split

Tags: vb.net, parsing, rss, split, cdata

Hey all i am trying to parse the following CDATA description:

```
 <description>
   <![CDATA[
     <p><b>Submission Date :</b> 2012-11-07 16:53:27<br/> <b>IP Address :</b> xx.xxx.xxx.xx<br/> <b>First Name :</b> dev<br/> <b>Email :</b> test3@here.com<br/> <b>18 yrs./Older :</b> YES<br/> <b>xxxxOffers :</b> <br/> </p>
   ]]>
</description>
```

Which looks like this when read in:

```
Submission Date : 2012-11-07 16:53:27
IP Address : xx.xx.xx.xx
First Name : dev
Email : test3@here.com
18 yrs./Older : YES
xxxxOffers : [space here]
```

Currently i do the following:

```
description = description.Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>", "").Replace("<b>", "").Replace("</b>", "").Replace("<br/>", "")
Dim descriptionArray() As String = Split(description, " : ")
```

Which yields the following:

[image]

which should be broken down as such:

```
(0)Submission Date
(1)2012-11-07 16:53:27
(2)IP Address
(3)xx.xxx.xxx.xx
(4)First Name
(5)dev
(6)Email
(7)test3@here.com
(8)18 yrs./Older
(9)YES
(10)xxxxOffers
(11)[space here]
```

I can not seem to find a way to split the CDATA into each value without using a SPLIT with the denominator of **":"** which makes it all go off of whack since the time (**16:53:27**) has the **":"** in it already.

So i tried to side-step that by checking for **" : "** but still does not give me the needed results I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to get info in a dictionary oriented object. So you will have description and value in a single call. by example you can do something like :

```
Dim ht as new HashTable   
' by <br>, you will have  : <p><b>Submission Date :</b> 2012-11-07 16:53:27 as first line
For each inLine as string in split(description,"<br/>")
    '<p><b>Submission Date : and 2012-11-07 16:53:27
    dim keyValue as string = split(inLine,"</b>")
    'then clean up <p>,<b>,.... remaining either by "<" and ">" or full tag
    'add(key,value)
    ht.add(keyValue(0), keyValue(1))
Next
```

If for any reason you do not want to use an Enumerable Object, you can use this as base line.